# CSS Source Maps not Loading Properly in Google Chrome

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, sass, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on one branch from two different machines. The css source maps are not showing on one of the two in Element. I regenerated the maps, made sure the Chrome's developer settings are identical between the two machines, and reloaded Chrome.

Just to clarify, in case my assumption of source map is incorrect, here're two pictures of both machines and their difference:

- Expected:

  [image]
- Broken:

  [image]